# Unable to successfully validate an access token from Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

I am using the Microsoft Graph API along with Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) to acquire access tokens and I can successfully retrieve the access token, id token and refresh token. I can also successfully validate the **id token**. However, I cannot do the same for the **access token** as I'm getting this error:

```
raise InvalidSignatureError('Signature verification failed')
jwt.exceptions.InvalidSignatureError: Signature verification failed
```

I've reviewed as best as I can the microsoft documentation regarding validation here:
[Microsoft identity platform access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens)

For validation, I can successfully decode using the jwt.ms site for jwt validation. So I know the tokens are good. I can see from the decode the claims and extract the **aud**(audience) and **iss**(issuer). These values are not the same for the id token (which I can successfully validate).

I am using the public keys from the following url as documented:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT ID>/discovery/keys
```

So, what I missing in regards to validating the access token? (if I can validate the id token with no issues). How else can i troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I knew, we do not need to validate Microsoft graph signature. Because MsGraph recognized an opportunity to improve security for users. They achieved this by putting a ‘nonce’ into the jwt header. The JWS is signed with a SHA2 of the nonce, the `nonce` is replaced before the JWS is serialized. To Validate this token, the `nonce` will need to be replaced with the SHA2 of the `nonce` in the header. Now this can change since there is no public contract.  So When calling Microsoft Graph, you should treat access tokens as opaque. For more details, please refer [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/609#issuecomment-524434987) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts)

Comment: appreciate the response. both answers helped me understand the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Jim's answer is correct and there are 2 use cases really - so it depends what you are trying to do:

- Getting an access token for Microsoft resources - such as Graph - in which case you don't validate them
- Getting a token for your own API resources, in which case you need to validate them. For this to work you need to 'expose an API scope' to get a different type of access token

Behaviour is not intuitive in my opinion, since I like to build standards based solutions. If it helps, here is a [visual blog post of mine](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/) on getting the second scenario above working.

Comment: Gary, you're blog really helped break it down. Appreciate the response in this.